# Generating a deterministic random function that takes into account the date as well as a long ID

Tags: general-topology, algorithms, numerical-methods, random, data-analysis

In SQL Server there's a function **RAND()** that if you pass a seed to it will return a pseudo random number based on the seed. No matter when you pass that same seed into this function, it will always generate the same pseudo random number.

I'm a database programmer and am having a tough time deciding on an algorithm that will help me to pass in a seed into RAND() as well as a large number, approximately 10^9, to get a pseudo random number based on the date and ID.

Currently I have something like this:

```
FLOOR(RAND(@seed * LOG([p].[patientid]) * 1000)
```

where the **patientid** is the large number (10^9) and the @**seed** is some unique integer that is a function of the date today.

The result is a different value for every patientid, and you can go back in time because the @seed is just a function of Datetime.

**Can you share with me an algorithm that is a deterministic random function that takes into account the date as well as a long ID and will generate a result that will equal something random between 1 and 10,000, and if you give it the same seed, it will always return the same value ?**

Comment: please note that i am not looking specifically for a sql solution, i am simply looking for an algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems like you are looking for a [hash function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)  You are already using the floor(10000*rand(x)) function as a hash function.  If you want to be extra careful about collisions (to prevent increased chances of collision if log(patientid) is somehow related to seed), you could try

```
FLOOR(1000*RAND(seed + FLOOR(10000*RAND(patientid))))
```

Because this hashes the patientid before combining it with the seed, it should eliminate any relationship between the two, and give you optimal hash performance.

A much more standard way to do this would be to use a standard hash function like sha-256 [which sql server provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx).  In this case, you would just do `SHA256(seed, patientid)` which would give you 256 bits of random output.  SHA256 takes an array of bytes as the input, so really by `SHA256(seed,patientid)` I mean something like `SHA256(seed+","+patientid)`  Where the seed and patientid are combined into a single string by concatenating them together.  From the output of the sha256 function, you could extract a number between 1 and 10000, or whatever you want.

Comment: will it generate a result that will equal something like a random number between 1 and 10,000??

Comment: There are many different senses of "random". It is important to distinguish between uniformity, collision resistance, inversion resistance, etc. (check out the hash function article I linked). Using a cryptographic hash function like sha256 is going to be random in pretty much all of these ways, but if you can be specific about what you need out of the "random number", you could probably use something simpler and quicker for your use case.

Comment: thank you very much, this is probably what i need, however could you explain how i would be able to do this:  "From the output of the sha256 function, you could extract a number between 1 and 10000"

Comment: If you look at the first  four bits of the output, for example, it will represent a 32 bit integer which is between 0 and 4.3 billion.  If you take that number modulo 10000, it will be extremely close to uniformly distributed between 0 and 10000.